# Unity 5.2 Animator window / tab

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

When I double-click on an `animator controller` to launch it, the animator tab appears, but when I run the editor, I don't get the usual *flow*, *operations*, etc... I only get a static view of the *states* and *transition* *arrows* between them. My *parameters* do not show the changes they go through either.

I have multiple animations and can switch between them when certain game conditions occur, but nothing really shows when I do so, to see the flow of control, what happens, what goes wrong, the switching, the progress bar, etc...

I have the latest `Unity 5.2.0f3` so I wondered if it is just me or others are having a similar problem...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I think I should remove it myself.

Comment: You can try asking on gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do is this: Once we hit the play in the editor mode (and have the animator window docked on one side, of course) we just go and click the object in the hierarchy for which we want to analyse the animation flow. And the animator window will start showing the states and the progress bar.

Also, after upgrading to Unity 5.2, it is worth checking the values that were previously set for transition states, for example if vSpeed is greater than 0.1 then start walking. All my set values were messed up; i.e. changed.